# Unable to select values greater or equal to one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was testing my PostgreSQL query that was designed to get the balance and id where the balance is greater than or equal to 1:

```
myQuery = "SELECT balance, id FROM address WHERE balance >= 1 AND id IN (...)"   # '...' means some id's
```

and I wrote code to show the result of this query in a .txt file:

```
conn = pg2.connect(...)
...
file = open("C:\...\.txt", "w")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(myQuery)
data = cursor.fetchall()
for datum in data:
    file.write(str(datum[0]) + " " + datum[1] + "\n")
```

I checked the .txt file after the connection ends, and there was nothing in the .txt file. However, when I changed the query:

```
myQuery = "SELECT balance, id FROM address WHERE balance >= 0 AND id IN (...)"   # '...' means some id's and they are exactly same with those of the first query
```

and re-checked the .txt file after the connection ends, there were several results, and more interestingly, some of the results had a balance larger than 1. In other words, there were results like this:

```
0.12316 address1  # a result I expected...
57.12354 address2  # ...What?
3.24654 address3  # Why do these results appear only for the second query?
```

Why does this happen? Am I mis-understanding WHERE, AND, IN operator?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is ... you are asking for `balance >=0`, and `57.12354 >=0`, is it not? I'm guessing what you really want is `WHERE balance between 0 an 1`

Comment: All three of those values are >= 0 so I would expect those results. Every number greater than or equal to zero, including 0.12, 57.1, 3.2... etc.

Comment: The problem is that two of those results are also larger than 1 as the first query, but they were not returned.

Comment: Oh so you aren't getting results for the first query? No doubt it's the hidden `IN` values then.

Comment: @richyen: I'm sorry, my English is not fluent... The data I initially wanted to get are balances and id's whose balance is larger than 1 (```balance >= 1```), so I wrote the first query, and I got no data on the .txt file. And, when I changed the query to ```balance >= 0```, I got bunch of data. The problem is that there was a result like ```52343.2313 address1``` on the second query's .txt file, which is the data expected to be on the first query's .txt file. It only appears on the second query's .txt file.

Comment: @FedericoS: Yup, they didn't appear on the first query's result.

Comment: @JacobH: Hmm... Is the IN clause the problem?

Comment: 1. Did you check it in Postgres yet?
2. The logic wrong only when you make it FALSE (some how).
With 2 query, i have to said that: 3.24654<1 or 57.12354 <1
If not, pls remove the "ID in ()" and check again (just to make sure you don't mess it up).

For the first result, maybe the TYPE problem make it. is it INT?